# separate a string with multiple seperators AND extract single characters only

Tags: python, regex, string, list, findall

Say I have a data string that can have formatting that varies. Nominally the data in the string would be seperated by spaces but that's not always the case, so a simple `.split(' ')` won't work in this instance.

An example string is:

```
string = '2012 05 06 04:20:00.0500 FOOBAR 4.7E+10 -55 33.0 555~2767 B 12 \r\n'
```

To get all the numbers I need, which can contain exponents, start with -, +, or ~, or not have a space separating them I can use:

```
re.findall(r'[~+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?', string)
# giving the result;
['2012', '05', '06', '04', '20', '00.0500', '4.7E+10', '-55', '33.0', '555', '~2767', '12']
```

I also need just the single character (in this case `B`) from the string. This single character can be either B,F, or O and I can get this and avoid the `FOOBAR` in my string by using:

```
re.findall(r'((?:(?:\b))[FBO]\b)', string)
# giving the result:
['B']
```

But what I need is to get a result that combines the two results above. I could always append the list with the second result, but I would really like the position of the results in the corresponding list to appear in the order in which they exist in the original string `string`. That is, I want a list that looks like:

```
['2012', '05', '06', '04', '20', '00.0500', '4.7E+10', '-55', '33.0', '555', '~2767', 'B', '12']
```

Any ideas? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Don't use `str` as your variable name even if it is just for this example. You are shadowing the built-in [`str`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str) so it cannot be called .

Comment: A lapse of judgement naming my string for this example... I changed it to `string` in the hopes that others won't follow me down that dark, one-way street.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
re.findall(r'([~+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?|(?:(?:\b))[FBO]\b)', str)
```

This returns:

```
['2012', '05', '06', '04', '20', '00.0500', '4.7E+10', '-55', '33.0', '555', '~2767', 'B', '12']
```

Also, not to nag, but overwriting the Python type `str` with a variable name made be shudder for a second there.